# Нижний прочерк под кавычками, что это и как это убрать?

Tags: macos, macbook

При вводе текста где угодно, где бы я не вводил эти знаки " ' ^ ` появляется прямо под ними, нижний дефис или нижнее тире, выглядит это примерно _

Как избавиться от этого?

Во всех редакторах кода, у меня теперь проблемы, т.к. я открываю кавычки и надо нажать пробел, чтобы текст шел внутри кавычек. И самое что интересное это только на английской раскладке! Я думал проблема в редакторах, долго разбирался, но потом хоть в браузере хоть где начал вводить это и вижу этот зловещий нижний прочерк

Стоит мак ос high sierra.

[image: Ковычка]

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, у вас раскладка U.S. International – PC, или подобная. Перейдите в System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Sources -> уберите из списка эту раскладку и добавьте вместо неё любую другую англоязычную. Проверил на British и US, подчёркивания не ставится.